# How to Integrate Enterprise Library Validation Application Block ValidationResults between WCF and ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, wcf, validation, enterprise-library

Enterprise Library Validation Application Block (VAB) integrates with ASP.NET and also with WCF.

Is there a way to integrate ValidationResults created in WCF with ASP.NET?

e.g. an ASP.NET web page invokes a WCF service.  The WCF service validates the data using VAB and returns validation information via a FaultContract.  The ASP.NET page can take the results and display some error messages.  However, a common approach is to indicate which fields have errors (e.g. inline message or asterisk).  It seems that most of these approaches will involve being able to correlate the validation result with a control or with a validator.

I don't think there is an out of the box solution but was also curious if anyone had done this and what their approach was.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since there is no out of the box solution and there aren't any answers posted, I will share what I implemented.  I'm not in love with the approach but it is working for me.

**Overview**

The basic approach is for the ASP.NET page to populate a mapping between properties on the DataContract objects to the ClientId of the control that is being validated.  When a validation error occurs the ClientId is returned back from the service to the asp.net page as part of a FaultContract.  Then the details from the FaultException are extracted; the ASP.NET page retrieves the ClientId of the control that caused the error and appropriate action can be taken (e.g. change control look and feel or set the text on a validator).

**Details**

All of the DataContract objects inherit from a base class that exposes a Dictionary.  This dictionary is used to map object properties to ASP.NET controls.  In the Dictionary, the key is the property name on the DataContract object and the value is the ClientId of the control.  Before invoking a service, the client must attach the Dictionary to the DataContract object.

When a ValidationResult is created by Enterprise Library it contains a property called Target which is the object that was validated.  ValidationResult also contains a property called key which is the name of the property from the target object that was validated.  The ValidationResult key is also a key into the Dictionary that was set in the ASP.NET page before calling the service.

With the ValidationResult key, the ASP.NET supplied information (ClientId) can be extracted from the ValidationResult Target.  The information is then added as the Tag of the ValidationResult.  Unfortunately, Tag is a readonly property so it has to be set by creating a new ValidationResult and passing the tag to the constructor.

The collection of ValidationResults is then transformed to a pre-existing CustomValidationResults collection (which looks just like ValidationResult) that we needed to use.  The CustomValidationResults are then added to a custom ValidationFault and a FaultException is thrown.

The ValidationFaults are then extracted from the FaultException in the ASP.NET page.  The ValidationFault contains the ClientId of the control which is associated with the error so the page can choose to display the Messages as it sees fit.