# Validating Domain Objects and Displaying Validation Results on the View

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, validation, domain-driven-design

I have a client -> service -> server, architecture and I want to introduce validation.

I have dtos being passed over the service and get transformed into domain objects on the server.

Say if a user enters in a value and I need to check this value against the database to see if it exists and if so return an error and highlight the field, how would I best go about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a pretty complicated topic, but there are frameworks like [Rocky Lhotka's CSLA.NET](http://www.lhotka.net/cslanet/) and the upcoming [Microsoft WCF RIA Services](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/RiaServices) that attempt to abstract some of the challenges of maintaining a consistent set of validation rules on both the client and server. There really isn't a silver bullet and I suspect any answers that fit in a Stack Overflow response will only scratch the surface so I'll just point you to those two frameworks which may give you some ideas.

You'll also want to look into the [IDataErrorInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.idataerrorinfo.aspx) interface in .NET which both Windows Forms and WPF can use to communicate errors in business objects back to the UI.

Answer (score 2):

As Josh mentions, there is no silver bullet for this.  [Here is the approach I used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1703423/how-to-integrate-enterprise-library-validation-application-block-validationresult) to achieve what you are asking about using Enterprise Library Validation Application block.  It's not particularly elegant (which still bugs me!) but it is working.