# Self validation using enterprise library, on ASP.MVC & WCF

Tags: asp.net-mvc, wcf, validation, enterprise-library

I have an asp.mvc based website, that calls an app server using WCF. The controller receives a request as  follows:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult foo(MyClass mc)
{
   using (var client = new MyWCFServiceClient())
   {
       client.SendMyClass(mc);
   }

}
```

`MyClass` sits in a class library and looks like that:

```
[HasSelfValidation]
public class MyClass 
{

    [SelfValidation]
    public void Validate(ValidationResults validationResults)
    {
        do..
        validationResults.AddResult(new ValidationResult(..));
    }
}
```

What I want is for the validation functionality to be called when the controller action is invoked (and asp.mvc creates the instance mc) as well as on my app server when the data arrives there.

That does not happen - the validation never gets called. What am I doing wrong and what is the best practice for such a case?

Answer (score 0):

If am understanding you correctly then you have two seprate validation concern.

1. Validation at client level that is your class at mvc.
2. Validation at the service side which need to validated at your data contract level.

Refer this link
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/259327/Integrate-Validation-Block-with-WCF
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1703423/how-to-integrate-enterprise-library-validation-application-block-validationresul

Comment: I'm not sure you understood correctly. I'm not asking about client validation (JS/Jquery) that takes place before the request to the web server is sent, but validation in web server (on the controller). Moreover, I would like the validation logic to be implemented once other than having to write that twice and maintain the same logic in 2 different locations. Also, this article talks about WCF validation using the enterprise library in general while iIasked about the "selfValidation" mechanism.

Comment: check where you have added your code like this ?var objMyClass= new MyClass();
var validator = ValidationFactory.CreateValidator<MyClass>();
var results = validator.Validate(objMyClass);

Comment: You can refer this link also --http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/gilf/archive/2010/03/25/self-validation-in-validation-application-block.aspx